# 301 redirect only 1 page and not all it's sub pages

Tags: redirect

Currently I have this redirect

`Redirect 301 /partners https://mysomesite/ecosystem`

So it redirects correctly by redirecting https://mysomesite/partners to https://mysomesite/ecosystem

But now I have an issue with all the content under /partners/

Now these pages are linking to broken pages. I do not want this to happen.

https://mysomesite/partners/title1/ to https://mysomesite/ecosystem/title1/
https://mysomesite/partners/title2/ to https://mysomesite/ecosystem/title2/

So how to I redirect /partners/ without all its content underneath of it getting redirected also?

Comment: Similar question here - no idea can someone help here : [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62138400/how-can-i-redirect-the-main-homepage-and-other-subpages-seperately)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Redirect` directive appends rest of the old url path to its destination url and it can't be avoided.

If you don't want the trailing path to be appended to your new url and to redirect `/partner` to a specific location,  you can use `RedirectMatch` .

```
RedirectMatch 301 /partner/?$ http://example.com/ecosystem
```

Clear your browser cache before testing this.